# How to convert object deep properties in to another?

Tags: javascript

Following is a deeply nested object with properties recurring.

How to convert the following deeply nested object

```
const obj = {
    prop1: {
        properties: { value: {} },
    },
    prop2: {
        properties: { subProp: { properties: { value: {} } } },
    },
    prop3: {
        properties: { subProp: { properties: { subSubProp: { properties: { value: {} } } } } },
    },
};
```

into this :

```
const obj = {
    prop1: { value: {} },
    prop2: { subProp: { value: {} } },
    prop3: { subProp: { subSubProp: { value: {} } } },
};

//if properties exists, else leave as it is (in each level)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could build new objects and check if the value is an object and if `properties` exists. Then take either `properties` or the object for a recursive call.

```js
const
    removeProperties = object => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([key, value]) => [
            key,
            value && typeof value === 'object'
                ? removeProperties('properties' in value ? value.properties : value)
                : value
        ])
    ),
    obj = { prop1: { properties: { value: {} } }, prop2: { properties: { subProp: { properties: { value: {} } } } }, prop3: { properties: { subProp: { properties: { subSubProp: { properties: { value: {} } } } } } } };

console.log(removeProperties(obj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Without [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const
    removeProperties = object => Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([key, value]) => [
            key,
            value && typeof value === 'object'
                ? removeProperties('properties' in value ? value.properties : value)
                : value
        ])
        .reduce((object, [key, value]) => ({ ...object, [key]: value }), {}),
    obj = { prop1: { properties: { value: {} } }, prop2: { properties: { subProp: { properties: { value: {} } } } }, prop3: { properties: { subProp: { properties: { subSubProp: { properties: { value: {} } } } } } } };

console.log(removeProperties(obj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It should be done recursively. i.e. all deep levels.

Comment: currently this is going only one level.

Comment: Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor' - error. I'm using this in typescript/

Comment: Hi Nina,. Can you please answer this also?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62362111/how-to-transfer-props-of-an-object-from-one-location-to-another/62362652?noredirect=1#comment110295195_62362652

Comment: @reacggarav, i have no idea to the new question. btw have you ever accepted an answer? you get rewards as well for it.

Comment: The question is simple.  Just to transfer props of an obj from one level to another wherever you see corresponding placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively remove it

```js
 const obj = {
      prop1: {
        properties: { value: {} },
      },
      prop2: {
        properties: { subProp: { properties: { value: {} } } },
      },
      prop3: {
        properties: { subProp: { properties: { subSubProp: { properties: { value: {} } } } } },
      },
    };

function converter(obj){
  if(typeof obj !== "object") return

  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if(value.properties){
      obj[key] = value.properties
      delete value.properties
    }
    if(typeof obj[key] === "object"){
      converter(obj[key])
    }
  })
}

converter(obj)
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Can you please answer this also?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62362111/how-to-transfer-props-of-an-object-from-one-location-to-another/62362652?noredirect=1#comment110295195_62362652

Answer (score 1):

Try this, This recursion method will work for nested removing data also

```
const obj = {
  prop1: {
    properties: { value: {} },
  },
  prop2: {
    properties: { subProp: { properties: { value: {} } } },
  },
  prop3: {
    properties: { subProp: { properties: { subSubProp: { properties: { value: {} } } } } },
  },
};

function propsRemover(data) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([key, { properties }]) => [key, propsRemover({ ...properties })]));
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(propsRemover(obj)));
```

Comment: Can you please answer this also?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62362111/how-to-transfer-props-of-an-object-from-one-location-to-another/62362652?noredirect=1#comment110295195_62362652